# Why do I have "native crash" issues on my app?

Tags: android, native

### Background

I have a simple [**app-manager**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager) app, which doesn't have any native code in it.

### The problem

In the recent few weeks, I got crash reports from users via the developer console, seeing various "native crash" logs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some of those devices seem to be on quite a new Android version (7.0, for example), so I thought this shouldn't occur.

I don't even use so many libraries. Most are of Google itself.

### What I tried

There are similar questions on [**Google's website**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) being reported, but they don't have an answer.

### The question

Why do those crashes occur?

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I have seen that crash and the same kind of log when I had the app open while it was updating in background from PlayStore. So the when the download finished, and it started updating the app, the currently opened app crashed.

Comment: @BasuSingh But what did you do to solve this? Have you found any lead? Is it reproducible ? Have you tried to contact Google?  When I tried to report about it, I got "wrong forum" tag marked for it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=236549 . Looking at the users messages, they wrote that it always crash.

Comment: No lead though. If the reason I stated above turns out to be true, there's nothing we can do (You'll be sure if you read that thing again, precisely). Basically, what I thinks, what happens if your app is doing some work and suddenly it gets uninstalled because Play Store is updating your app.

Comment: I have also noticed similar crashed, and those too, in samsung devices. Looks like a Samsung issue to me, but my users are angry

Comment: @Usman Did they tell you when it occurs?

Comment: no, just relying on stack traces